# Django .simple_tag multiple arguments

Tags: python, django, django-templates, arguments, templatetags

I have a simple tag that takes 2 positional arguments like this:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
@register.simple_tag
def multi(a, b):    
    html='<h1> a+b </h1>
    return mark_safe(a+b)
```

And, I'm trying to use the function in my html file but I don't know how to pass the second argument, this is how I'm doing it. any ideas how can I get it? I got an error that says missing 1 required positional argument 'b':

```
{% load my_tags %}
{% multi 'text1' 'text2' %}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no other `{% multi ... %}` template tag?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the second argument then I get this message `'multi' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'b'`

Comment: When you have `{% multi 'text1' 'text2' %}` what does `b` print? Looking at your code it should work as-is other than ` html= f'<h1>{{ a + b }}</h1>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to concatenate your `a` and `b` arguments inside the string with no formatting logic so it was just returning  `<h1> a+b </h>` instead of `<h1>text1text2</h1>`. Then you were returning `mark_safe` while return `a+b` which was ignoring your `html` variable, so you should be returning `html` inside mark_safe.

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.simple_tag
def multi(a,b): 
    html = f'<h1>{ a + b }</h1>'
    return mark_safe(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [format_html()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) instead of [mark_safe()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) as shown below:

```py
from django.template import Library
from django.utils.html import format_html

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def multi(a, b): 
    html = format_html("<h1>{}{}</h1>", a, b)
    return html
```